# How to set the style and disable/enable buttons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Based on my code I have grayed out my images using the CSS (with #myImage)
and I am trying for the following

1. Need to set or remove the style when two ore more check boxes are checked so that the images are clear and bright (I mean with no gray/white background on the images)
2. And make the image buttons active.

I am trying to do that by getElementById, getElementsByname and can not get it right.

Can you please help with this and attached is the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="JavaScript">
function countCheckboxes ( ) {
        var form = document.getElementById('testForm');
        var count = 0;
        for(var n=0;n < form.length;n++){
          if(form[n].name == 'itemID[]' && form[n].checked){
            count++;

          }
        }

        if(count >2)
        {

        document.getElementById('myimage').style = "none";
        //document.getElementById('checkCount').innerHTML = count;
         document.getElementsByname('testing').disabled = false;
         document.getElementsByname('testing1').disabled = false;
        alert("total no of checkbox selected "+count)
        }
        else
        {
        document.getElementsByname('testing').disabled = true;
         document.getElementsByname('testing1').disabled = true;
        }
      }
/*
function diableQuoteBtns()
{
  document.getElementById('itembutton').disabled = false;


}*/
</script>
</head>
<style>
#myImage {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
}

/* or */

#wrapper {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* msie */
    background-color: #0000;
}
</style>
<body >
<form name="form1"  id="testForm">
<table>

    <tr>

        <td> <input type="checkbox" name="itemID[]" id="item1" value="1" onclick="countCheckboxes()" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="itemID[]"  id="item2" value="2" onclick="countCheckboxes()" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="itemID[]"  id="item3" value="3" onclick="countCheckboxes()" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="itemID[]"  id="item4" value="4" onclick="countCheckboxes()" >

        </td>
        <td><span class='my_class_item'>Item Name : </span></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<table>
<tr>

     <td align="center" colspan="6">
         <!---<a href="JavaScript:validatePage('myAction1');"><div id="wrapper"><img id="myImage" src="button_quote.gif" alt="" border="0" align="middle"></div></a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='my_class_item'><span class='bold'>-OR-</span></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="JavaScript:validatePage(''myAction2');"><div id="wrapper"><img id="myImage" src="button_quote.gif" border="0" align="middle"></div></a>--->

                <input type="image" disabled name="Testing"  id="myimage" src="button_quote.gif" border="0" align="middle" onClick="JavaScript:validateForm('myAction1');">
                <input type="image" disabled name="Testing1" id="myimage" src="button_quote.gif" border="0" align="middle" onClick="JavaScript:validateForm('myAction2');">
                </div>
          </td>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is an incredibly popular library, and for a good reason: it makes tasks like this trivial.

If you just download the latest version of jQuery (from www.jquery.com) and add it to the page you can set the disabled attribute and element styles very easily.

For example:

```
$('[name="testing"], [name="testing1"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('#myimage').css('display', 'none');
```

If, for whatever reason, you don't want to use jQuery, you can use the setAttribute method to set attributes directly:

```
document.getElementsByname('testing')[0].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Or, to set styles you just have to pick a particular style property and set it; for instance:

```
document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = "none";
```

For further info see:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. 

1. @Machineghost:Yes, I am looking for a solution in JavaScript and the code
document.getElementById('myimage').style.display = "none"; is making my image to disappear completely
<br>
2. Leron : Your code has input type as button and in my original code I have it as "image" and I am not able to use image in the as per your example and can't get it right.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Well, you need to change `'display', 'none'` to `'whateverCssPropertyYouWantToChange', 'theValueYouWantToChangeItTo'`.  Your code (`document.getElementById('myimage').style = "none";`) made it look like you were trying to hide the image.  If you're not, what are you trying to change about it?   Also, you really should put the comment for @Leron as a separate comment in his question, just because Stack Overflow won't alert him if you put the comment here.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this 
Is it something like this?

Comment: document.getElementById('myimage').background-color = ""

Basically I am not hiding the images completely, just graying out with background-color: #0000; as per my css code.

When I select more than two check boxes, I should set background-color: to nothing, so that the images are visible clearly to the users for completing their transaction.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You've got the right idea (though again, this would all be easier with jQuery).  The only issue I see is that you can't do `background-color` (as that's invalid JS), you have to do `backgroundColor` instead.  See the link I added to my answer for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v8hfbov2/). the code is a bit messy but the main issue was that when you execute `document.getElementsByName("Testing")` this gives you a collection of the elements with that name, so you need to iterate them and perform whatever actions you want on each one individually like so:

```
var imgElements = document.getElementsByName("Testing");
for (var i = 0, max = imgElements.length; i < max; i++) {
             imgElements[i].disabled = false               
        }
```

Other than that you are doing fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. 

1. Yes, I am looking for a solution in JavaScript and the code